# Seperating Day and Night Time by True False

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

I am a python and data training beginner. Currently working on a dummy taxi fare calculator data frame but to receive better results, I want to separate day-time and night-time from each other to calculate a better fare.

The code I currently have:

```
d['time'] = pd.to_datetime(d['start']).dt.strftime('%H:%M')

for time in d['time']:
    hourMin = time.split(":")
    hour = int(hourMin[0])
    mins = int(hourMin[1])
    if hour >= 6 and hour <= 20:
        if(hour == 18):
            if(mins > 0):
                dtime = '0'
            else:
                dtime = '1'
        else:
            dtime = '1'
    else:
        day_time = '0'
        
    dtime[:10]
    d['time'] = dtime
    
d.head()
```

When I run this, I receive `IndexError: list index out of range` error on this part `mins = int(hourMin[1])` .

I really appreciate any help I can get since I have been struggling on this for last 4-5 hours.

Comment: Regarding day/night logic, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64483571/6340496) might help with how you might simplify the logic; specifically the 'Example' section.

Comment: Add a print(hourMin) statement before the error could help you to understant what is going on.

Comment: @manu190466 since it can't process further it prints  `['0']`

Comment: @S3DEV I had a look into it, I think I am getting to logic but I am way too confused to understand this kind of a complex script right now

Answer (score 0):

I think you make it too complicated. You can compare the `.time` of the column with `time` objects:

```
(
    (time(6) <= di.time) & (di.time <= time(18))
) | (
    (di.time >= time(19)) & (di.time < time(21))
)
```

This thus checks if the time is between 6:00 and 18:00 (both inclusive), or 19:00 (inclusive) and 21:00 (exclusive).

This will also work more efficient. For example:

```
>>> di
DatetimeIndex(['2015-04-24 02:00:00', '2015-11-26 23:00:00',
               '2016-01-18 00:00:00', '2016-06-27 22:00:00',
               '2016-08-12 17:00:00', '2016-10-21 11:00:00',
               '2016-11-07 11:00:00', '2016-12-09 23:00:00',
               '2017-02-20 01:00:00', '2017-06-17 18:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
>>> ((time(6) <= di.time) & (di.time <= time(18))) | ((di.time >= time(19)) & (di.time < time(21)))
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
        True])
```

You can convert it to an `int` with `.astype(int)`:

```
>>> (((time(6) <= di.time) & (di.time <= time(18))) | ((di.time >= time(19)) & (di.time < time(21)))).astype(int)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am quite unsure about how can I apply this to my code. Can you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: `di = pd.to_datetime(d['start'])`, then you set it as `d['time'] = (((time(6) <= di.time) & (di.time <= time(18))) | ((di.time >= time(19)) & (di.time < time(21)))).astype(int)`.

Comment: Unfortunately receiving this error. `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: @aiox: but we do not call anything. You did import `from datetime import time`?

Comment: @aiox: furthermore any local variable named `time` should be renamed...

Comment: I checked all the previous lines. No `time`. I had it imported, I renamed it to test this but still no work. `di = pd.to_datetime(d['start'])
d['time'] = (((time(6) <= di.time) & (di.time <= time(18))) | ((di.time >= time(19)) & (di.time < time(21)))).astype(int)` Error :  `Series' object has no attribute 'time'`

Comment: @aiox: ah, but then it should be `di = pd.to_datetime(d['start']).dt` (so with `.dt`).

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has some promising sounding functions:
[pandas.DataFrame.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) and [pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html)

Unfortunately, `between_time` returns a DataFrame, and not a boolean Series. So it's not so convenient to use with `.loc`.

And `indexer_between_time` returns an integer array of index positions. Works with `.iloc`, but that is quite uncomfortable to us.

Furthermore both of them require the index to be of DateTime type.

First, some example data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = "2020-11-19 00:00",
                  end = "2020-11-19 23:59",
                  periods = 15),
                  columns = ["start"])
```

```
                 start
0  2020-11-19 00:00:00
1  2020-11-19 01:42:47
2  2020-11-19 03:25:34
3  2020-11-19 05:08:21
4  2020-11-19 06:51:08
5  2020-11-19 08:33:55
6  2020-11-19 10:16:42
7  2020-11-19 11:59:30
8  2020-11-19 13:42:17
9  2020-11-19 15:25:04
10 2020-11-19 17:07:51
11 2020-11-19 18:50:38
12 2020-11-19 20:33:25
13 2020-11-19 22:16:12
14 2020-11-19 23:59:00
```

Adding a new column, which will show with True / False if a row is `Daytime` or not.

```py
df["Daytime"] = False
```

Setting the index to start, the DateTime column:

```py
df = df.set_index("start")
```

```
                    Daytime
start                      
2020-11-19 00:00:00   False
2020-11-19 01:42:47   False
2020-11-19 03:25:34   False
2020-11-19 05:08:21   False
2020-11-19 06:51:08   False
2020-11-19 08:33:55   False
2020-11-19 10:16:42   False
2020-11-19 11:59:30   False
2020-11-19 13:42:17   False
2020-11-19 15:25:04   False
2020-11-19 17:07:51   False
2020-11-19 18:50:38   False
2020-11-19 20:33:25   False
2020-11-19 22:16:12   False
2020-11-19 23:59:00   False
```

Which are your boundaries for a timestamp to be DayTime?

```py
DayStart = "06:30:00"
DayEnd = "18:00:00"
```

Creating the integer array of matching rows. You can also set `include_start` and `include_end` to have open or closed intervals.

```py
DayTime = df.index.indexer_between_time(DayStart, DayEnd)
```

What do we get in return? A list of integers that match the index position.

```py
>>> array([ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

We can now use that to set the 0th column to `True`:

```py
df.iloc[DayTime,0] = True
```

```
                   Daytime
start                     
2020-11-19 00:00:00  False
2020-11-19 01:42:47  False
2020-11-19 03:25:34  False
2020-11-19 05:08:21  False
2020-11-19 06:51:08   True
2020-11-19 08:33:55   True
2020-11-19 10:16:42   True
2020-11-19 11:59:30   True
2020-11-19 13:42:17   True
2020-11-19 15:25:04   True
2020-11-19 17:07:51   True
2020-11-19 18:50:38  False
2020-11-19 20:33:25  False
2020-11-19 22:16:12  False
2020-11-19 23:59:00  False
```

Using the `between_time` function returns a DataFrame matching the criterion:

```py
df_DayFilter = df.between_time(DayStart, DayEnd)
```

```
                   Daytime
start                     
2020-11-19 06:51:08   True
2020-11-19 08:33:55   True
2020-11-19 10:16:42   True
2020-11-19 11:59:30   True
2020-11-19 13:42:17   True
2020-11-19 15:25:04   True
2020-11-19 17:07:51   True
```

I'd really like to know as well if there is a more elegant way to use `between_time`!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your broad explanation and example. That helped me a lot to understand the logic but I have a question. Since I have a data frame, `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = "2020-11-19 00:00", end = "2020-11-19 23:59",periods = 15), columns = ["start"])` how can I implement it to this part?

Comment: The quoted block of my code is simply to create a minimum sample DataFrame. Something to allow my answer to be tried out immediately. I don't know the structure of the DataFrame you're working with, so I created the bare minimum: just the datetime column named "start". If you add more information about the layout of your DataFrame, I can edit my answer accordingly.